# Reports With XSL

Tags: c#, xslt

I have the following concerns about reports in XSL. 
I am generating reports in XSL and I have a column "Type" that can be Q, A, N or T. And whenever you change the "Type" must change the page, or break-page! 
Someone knows something about it!?

Comment: If you are looking for elements in XSL-FO vocabulary that bring this functionality, you should retag accordingly. If you are using some "standar" XSLT stylesheet (like those for DocBook) you must add this information to the question. If you are running your own transformation, you need to provide a reduce input sample and an exact desired output. Otherwise this question is unanswerable.

Comment: I use css class that adds to an element which breaks page in print , you can see example at https://github.com/SiamandMaroufi/webreport

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your platform but the general answer is to do something like this in your XSLT:

```
<xs:element name="a">
  <xs:attribute name="href">
    <xs:text>ViewReport?row=</xs:text>
    <xs:value-of select="@rowid" />
    <xs:text>&op=q</text>
  </xs:attribute>
  <xs:text>Q</xs:text>
</xs:element>
```

When you click on the Q, it'll pull up ViewReport with the current row ID and a pointer to the Q operation. Naturally, you'll need another of these for the A, N, etc. operations.

Exactly how the link works will depend on your platform. I'm assuming a web-based system with HTTP GET parameters but you can adjust to your needs.